# Is this an efficient initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, stdarray

I want to make a mathematical vector class whose main data is an `std::array`. I also want to write the constructor to take in an `std::array` and initialize it to the data attribute. In my code I will template the type of elements and size of vector, but for now I will write code for a vector of four integers:

```cpp
class MyVector {
private:
    std::array<int,4> data;

public:
    MyVector(std::array<int,4> input)
        :data{ input } {}
}
```

And using implicit constructors I can define a `MyVector` object like:

`MyVector v({0, 1, 2, 3});`

My question is: is this initialization redundant? Am I creating an extra `std::array` only to through it away?

Does the compiler first create `input` from the list `{0, 1, 2, 3}` and then using the initializer list to copy that to the `data` attribute in the object? Or does the compiler just create the `std::array` in the memory address of the `data` attribute for the object. If I am creating an extra `std::array`, is there a more efficient way to input `int`s using the `{}` notation without creating an extra step of copying arrays? Remember, I want to accomplish this because I want the MyVector class to be templated, so the length of the `{}` is variable.

EDIT:
I have seen mentions of `std::initializer_list`. Is this essentially the same implantation of what I am doing or are there some compiler shortcuts? Can I use `std::initializer_list` for `std::array`s? I don't want to use `std::list` because I want MyVector class to be instantiated on automatic memory and not free memory.

Comment: With this [simple example](https://godbolt.org/z/bvePndrfx), the compiler is even smart enough to eliminate `MyVector` entirely (look at the assembly; it just prints a constant). The optimizer sees right through it.

Comment: It would be more normal to pass a const reference instead of a value. That way it's guaranteed not to have a redundant copy, even in unoptimized builds. Don't be afraid of providing multiple constructors for the different initialization styles you might want. Your data probably doesn't always come neatly packaged in a 4-element `std::array`.

Comment: Oh wow I see. I underestimated the optimizer. So when creating lots of MyVectors in a short amount of time, I should not worry about the extra copy step because the   optimizer will just get rid of that?

Comment: @paddy I eventually want to make a vec2, vec3, vec4 classes for ints and floats, those are the main vectors I will be using. However, making individual constructors for each size and type seems really redundant. Which is why I wanted to template it, and put all of the math functions in the templated class.

Comment: Any given compiler optimization depends on the optimizer, optimization level, etc. This is a fairly common optimization though. As for "making individual constructors... seems really redundant" - properly used templates parametrized on type name (plus possibly typedefs to provide convenient aliases) should be able to handle this if designed properly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik is it compiler optimization? Or is it that std::array has a move constructor and so it avoids copying. Similar to what is said here: https://youtu.be/ehMg6zvXuMY?t=401

Comment: @FrancisGodinho In [the example](https://godbolt.org/z/bvePndrfx), the compiler didn't even allocate space for `MyVector` instance, let alone initialize it. It optimized the whole object away, `std::array` and all.

Comment: See the [As-If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) TL;DR: If you can't tell the difference in the program's output, the compiler can do whatever it wants to your code. This messes up a lot of people who write time-waster loops (`eg: while (true);`) or really long `for` loops that produce no output. They wind up here wondering why the loop took zero time. If it does nothing observable other than waste time, the compiler probably removes it.

Comment: _I eventually want to make a vec2, vec3, vec4 classes for ints and floats_ might be a good fit for a class template.

Comment: Have you considered: `class MyVector : protected std::array<int,4> { using std::array<int,4>::array; };` If you don't need any code inside the constructor, this might be the easiest way to do it.